# How to configure Google App Engine for nodejs to run only npm start, and do not run npm install?

Tags: node.js, gcloud

We have a NodeJS project. We decided to commit into the repository our `node_modules` directory. When I deploy with `gcloud app deploy` I would like Google App Engine to *not* run `npm install` on my project.
By default it runs `npm install && npm start`, I need only `npm start`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default `gcloud` will skip `node_modules` directory, however you can control which files are ignored in deployment by creating a [.gcloudignore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore).

If you don't create a `.gcloudignore` file `gcloud` will create a default one which contains the following:

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
node_modules/
```

You can create your `.gcloudignore` without the `node_modules/` directory.

You can also specify the dependencies that you want to be installed in the  `package.json` file. For more information on how to specify dependencies, you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies).

Comment: OK. Maybe I wasn't clear enough with my question. I know how package.json works. We use it to install node modules. So far so good. What I want is `gcloud` to not run `npm install`. We decided to commit the modules installed by `npm install` on dev computer to the repository so that we have the same version on all computers. Now, I want to be sure I don't rely on gcloud installing from the Internet. I want it to use the node_modules I pushed to my repository.

Comment: @PatkosCsaba In this case you will have to customize the runtime building a Docker image. You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) for a reference.